# Spectrum of closure of function field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Take $V$ and $W$ to be projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$ and $m$, respectively. Let $f : V \to W$ be a fibre space, i.e., $f$ is a surjective map whose generic fiber is connected. In a 1983 paper of Viehweg (Weak Positivity and the Additivity of the Kodaira dimension for Certain Fibre Spaces), Viehweg introduces the notion of *variation*:

**Definition:** The variation, denoted $\text{var}(f)$, is the smallest number $k$ such that there is a subfield $L$ of $\overline{\mathbb{C}(W)}$ of transcendence degree $k$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a variety $F$ over $L$ with $F \times_{\text{Spec}(L)} \text{Spec}(\overline{\mathbb{C}(W)})$ birational to the fibre $V_w = f^{-1}(w)$.

**Aim:** Understand the notion of variation geometrically.

Comment: Which paper, where? It might be easier to give you intuition if we know some more of the surrounding context. In general, what's going on here is that you're just base-extending a variety to an algebraically closed field - are you familiar with examples of this, independent of this paper of Viehweg you're reading?

Comment: @KReiser I will give more details to my question :)

Comment: @KReiser I understand base-changes (more or less), but do not see why you would consider $\text{Spec}$ of $\overline{\mathbb{C}(W)}$.

Comment: @ABitTooCurious I think you might find it useful to first think about families of curves of genus at least two $V\to W$. Let's say $\dim W=1$ to begin. To say that the family $f:V\to W$ is isotrivial is equivalent to $V_{\bar{K(W)}}$ being trivial (this is not a trivial statement). In other words, to see whether $V\to W$ is isotrivial or not it suffices to  look at the "geometric generic fibre" of $V\to W$. Note that being non-isotrivial is the same as the image of the moduli map $W\to M_g$ being one-dimensional (or: the moduli map is non-constant). If $\dim W>1$....

Comment: ...things are more complicated. The moduli map $W\to M_g$ can be a point (i.e., the family is isotrivial), but it could also be positive-dimensional. However, the dimension of the image of $W\to M_g$ is of course at *most* the dimension of $W$. Intuitively speaking, the family $V\to W$ has maximal variation in moduli if this dimension is as large as possible, i.e., equal to $\dim W$. (With this definition:  if $\dim W > 3g-3$, then the family $V\to W$ can't have maximal variation in moduli.)

Comment: I'd also recommend you simply think of "maximal variation in moduli" as meaning that the moduli map is *generically finite onto its image*. For example, if the moduli map is quasi-finite (think about what this means for each fibre...), then your family $V\to W$ has maximal variation in moduli. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you so much for your comments! Can there be intermediate values of the variation? That is, from your comments, the variation is bounded between $0$ and $\dim(W)$, are there instances where the variation is strictly between this range? Moreover, is there a nice way to think about this _intermediate variation_ geometrically?

Comment: The intermediate variation occurs when $W$ itself has a fibration $g: W \to Z$ and the birational type of the fiber over $w \in W$ depends only on $g(w)$, with $\dim Z< \dim W$ but $\dim Z$ not $0$. For example, we can take the product of a maximal variation family with a trivial family.